# How to set correct video codec in mediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-camera2, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder to record videos. While setting up mediaRecorder, I can set video codec to one of [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder).

I am using following code to setup MediaRecorder

```
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.HEVC; ///Hardcode value
profile.videoFrameRate = 30;
profile.videoFrameWidth = videoSize.getWidth();
profile.videoFrameHeight = videoSize.getHeight();
mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
```

I don't want to hardcode videoCodec to HEVC since it is not supported on all the devices.

I am looking for some API which I can use to query list of available video codecs and then figure out which one to use. But I can't find anything in the MediaRecorder docs.

So, Is there any way to get the available video codecs for a device?
Any help is appreciated.

PS: I am using camera2 API

Comment: Look at my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56471858/5550161